# tcolorbox & parskip & minted

Tags: tcolorbox, minted, parskip

I want to use minted code extract within tcolorbox, but it fails to properly set the parskip of the first box. I already use `parskip=false` inside the tcolorbox, but it doesn't solve the issue.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{paperwidth=7in, paperheight=9in, bindingoffset=0.35in, left=0.7in, right=0.7in, top=1in, bottom=0.8in}
\usepackage{float}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.05 in}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{upquote}%straight quotes in minted
\setminted{fontsize=\small, breaklines=true, breakbefore=., breakafter={,,+,~,\space,:}, showspaces, space=~, frame=single, numbers=left, numbersep=5pt, highlightcolor={red!25}, fontfamily=tt}
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\sffamily\tiny\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\needspace{1\baselineskip}}

\newlength{\fancyvrbtopsep}
\newlength{\fancyvrbpartopsep}
\makeatletter
\FV@AddToHook{\FV@ListParameterHook}{\topsep=\fancyvrbtopsep\partopsep=\fancyvrbpartopsep}
\makeatother
\setlength{\fancyvrbtopsep}{1pt} 
\setlength{\fancyvrbpartopsep}{1pt}

\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.35in}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{Python}[1][]{
parbox=false,
parskip=0.05in,
colback=white,
colframe=black!50!white,
coltitle=white,
enlarge top by=0.5\baselineskip,
enlarge bottom by=0\baselineskip,
fonttitle=\bfseries,breakable,enhanced jigsaw,
title=Python~#1}
\newenvironment{mycolorbox}[1][]
  {\if\detokenize{#1}\relax\relax
      \begin{tcolorbox}
    \else
      \begin{tcolorbox}[#1]
    \fi
  \parskip=5\baselineskip \advance\parskip by 0pt plus 2pt
  \parindent=0pt
}
  {\end{tcolorbox}}
\begin{document}
\begin{Python}[dummy text]
dummy text
\begin{minted}{python}
dummy code
\end{minted}
dummy text
\begin{minted}{python}
dummy code
\end{minted}
\end{Python}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Had the same issue. Only solution I was able to employ was to use keys `before` and `after` to set whitespace before and after `tcolorbox`, but it is not perfectly reliable workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find replacing `parbox=false` by `before upper={\setlength{\parskip}{.05in}}` solves the problem.

Additionally, you can use

```
\fvset{
  listparameters={\topsep=\fancyvrbtopsep\partopsep=\fancyvrbpartopsep}
}
```

instead of

```
\makeatletter
\FV@AddToHook{\FV@ListParameterHook}{\topsep=\fancyvrbtopsep\partopsep=\fancyvrbpartopsep}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Changing 'parbox=false' by 'before upper={\setlength{\parskip}{.05in}}' worked! Thank you so much :)